# "More Stack Exchange Communities" search doesn't work in chat server

Tags: bug, chat, search, stack-exchange-button, communities-list

When you go into the chat server and enter anything into the "more Stack Exchange communities" search bar, no suggestions pop up:

[image: Image of the word "stack" entered in the "more Stack Exchange communities" search bar (from the chat server), with no corresponding community suggestions]

Also note that the input text is badly offset to the left so that the search icon is blocking part of it.

Just for comparison, entering the same keywords into the search bar when not in the chat server gives:

[image: Image of the word "stack" entered in the "more Stack Exchange communities" search bar (from the main site), with the corresponding community suggestions]

Comment: The version of the top bar that chat uses has been deprecated since 2017; it also can't load Teams content.